# Trying to write to specific key in dictionary, but it is writing to all keys in the entire dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to count a lot of different variables from a list of characters, and put them in a nested dictionary. However, because of the specific task, the dictionaries that are "next to" each other all have the same keys inside of them, as shown below in dataDict. 
I am trying to count things with specific values, and so whenever I try and add 1 to the value of a key, all items with that key across the dictionaries add 1 to their value, instead of just the one item that I want to add the 1 to. I am wondering if there is a way to stop this happening, or if there is a better way to do what I am trying to do.
The keys must be the same, as the general shape of the whole dictionary is:

```
{'a':{1:{'a':0, 'b':0, 'c':0 , ...}, 2 :{'a':0, ...}, ...}, 'b':{...}}
```

The code below is meant to show what is happening, in reality all of the keys to access dataDict are variables, but they all work fine.

I have looked at using counters, but as far as I can tell, I run into the same issue.

```
dataDict = {'G':{1:{'a':0}, 2:{'a':0}, 3:{'a':0}}, 'L':{1:{'a':0}, 2:{'a':0}, 3:{'a':0}}}

characters = ["l", "i", "s", "t", " ", "o", "f", " ", "c", "h", "a", "r", "a", "c", "t", "e", "r", "s"]

for i in string:
    if tweet.index(i) > 2:
        dataDict['G'][1]['a'] += 1
```

**Expected:**

```
dataDict = {'G':{1:{'a':15}, 2:{'a':0}, 3:{'a':0}}, 'L':{1:{'a':0}, 2:{'a':0}, 3:{'a':0}}}
```

**Actual:**

```
dataDict = {'G':{1:{'a':15}, 2:{'a':15}, 3:{'a':15}, 'L':{1:{'a':15}, 2:{'a':15}, 3:{'a':15}}}
```

The code to make dataDict is:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

def makeDict():
    string = """abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890().,:;'" []//|\\!@#$%^&*_+-=<>?~`"""

    overall = defaultdict(Counter)
    dictionary = {}

    listofstuff = list(string)

    for i in listofstuff:
        dictionary[str(i)] = 0

    for a in listofstuff:
        overall[str(a)] = {1 : dictionary, 2 : dictionary, 3 : dictionary}

    return overall
```

Comment: There is some code missing that may help solve your issue. Is this the actual way you are constructing dataDict? It looks like you have assigned the same dictionary to multiple keys, dictionaries are mutable and every reference to the same dict will update when you change it in any place

Comment: Yes, this is the way dataDict is constructed, where the same dictionaries are assigned to multiple keys, but this is the way it has to be in order to get the data I want. I would think that even though the dictionaries are the same, they are seperated by their keys, and so they shouldn't all be written to.

Comment: Can you share the code that you are actually using to construct dataDict? I’m almost certain that you are assigning the same dict “{‘a’: 0}” to multiple keys

Comment: Yeah the problem is that you’ve assigned “dictionary” to multiple keys. You need to assign copies of the dictionary. “copy.deepcopy(dictionary)”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries are of reference types in Python. It depends how you have formed `dataDict` here.  I think you are using/assigning same variable in many places and all these are pointing to same memory location.

So updating any one of them is like reflecting values of others.

For a quick understanding, have a look at below 3 code snippets executed on Terminal.

> Problem

```
>>> d = {"a": 0}
>>> 
>>> data = {1: d, 2: d, 3: d}
>>> 
>>> data
{1: {'a': 0}, 2: {'a': 0}, 3: {'a': 0}}
>>> 
>>> data[1]['a'] += 1
>>> 
>>> data
{1: {'a': 1}, 2: {'a': 1}, 3: {'a': 1}}
>>>
```

> Solution 1

```
>>> # 1st way
... 
>>> data = {1: {**d}, 2: {**d}, 3: {**d}}
>>> data
{1: {'a': 1}, 2: {'a': 1}, 3: {'a': 1}}
>>> 
>>> data[1]['a'] += 1
>>> 
>>> data
{1: {'a': 2}, 2: {'a': 1}, 3: {'a': 1}}
>>> 
>>>
```

> Solution 2 (using deepcopy)

```
>>> # 2nd way
...
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> 
>>> d
{'a': 1}
>>> 
>>> data = {1: deepcopy(d), 2: deepcopy(d), 3: deepcopy(d)}
>>> data
{1: {'a': 1}, 2: {'a': 1}, 3: {'a': 1}}
>>> 
>>> data[1]['a'] += 1
>>> data
{1: {'a': 2}, 2: {'a': 1}, 3: {'a': 1}}
>>>
```